# Shifting characters in a string, not getting complete output

Tags: java, arrays, char

Having trouble getting an complete output. When I run my program as is it performs the desired shifts of the characters but only for the first 16 characters, after that it just outputs null or i get an index out of bounds.

I've already tried changing reading the length of the string but I am stuck and dont know where to go from here, any advice? how would you show how to print the remaining string?

```
package com.sanfoundry.setandstring;

import java.io.IOException;

public class shiftRows {
    /*
     *  The first row remains the same. Shift the second row one position to the left. 
     *  Shifts the third row two positions to the left. Finally, shift the fourth row
     *  three positions to the left.
     */


    public static String shiftRows(String str, int shiftNum)
    {
        char[] out = new char[4];
        if(shiftNum==1)
        {
            out[0]=str.charAt(1); //shifts char at position 0 
            out[1]=str.charAt(2); //shifts char at position 1 to pos 2
            out[2]=str.charAt(3); //shifts char at position 2 to pos 3
            out[3]=str.charAt(0); //shifts char at position 3 to pos 1
        }
        if(shiftNum==2)
        {
            out[0]=str.charAt(2);
            out[1]=str.charAt(3);
            out[2]=str.charAt(0);
            out[3]=str.charAt(1);
        }
        if(shiftNum==3)
        {
            out[0]=str.charAt(3);
            out[1]=str.charAt(0);
            out[2]=str.charAt(1);
            out[3]=str.charAt(2);
        }
        return new String(out);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("SHIFT ROWS: " );

        String[] input= new String[16]; //string prints 4x4 block of 16char

        String[] output= new String[16]; //outputs in 4x4 block

        String random = "AJUYJTXQHUHXICWYYMGHTRKQHQPWKYVGLPYSPWGOINTOFASDF"; //random string

        for (int i = 0, n = 0; i < 4; i++, n+=4) { //i<4
            input[i] = random.substring(0+n, 4+n); //reads length of random string and performs shift
        }

        output[0] = input[0];
        for(int i=1; i<4; i++)//i<4
        {
            output[i] = shiftRows(input[i],i);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<16; i++) //loops to print in 4x4 block
        {
            System.out.println(output[i]); //prints the output
        }

    }
}
```

my output:

```
AJUY
TXQJ
HXHU
YICW
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null

desired output:

AJUY
TXQJ
HXHU
YICW
YMGH
RKQT
PWHQ
GKYV
LPYS
WGOP
TOIN
MFOP
OAAA
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
```

Comment: Could you give the sample string that you are passing to the method?

Comment: String random = "AJUYJTXQHUHXICWYYMGHTRKQHQPWKYVGLPYSPWGOINTOFASDF";

Comment: `for(int i=1; i<4; i++)` - you want to shift 16 strings, so why are you only looping over 3 of them?

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues,

you were not handling shiftNum 0
The for loop which was splitting the string was not right

Please see the below code which is providing the desired results

```
package com.sanfoundry.setandstring;

import java.io.IOException;

public class shiftRows {
    public static String shiftRows(String str, int shiftNum) {
        char[] out = new char[4];
        if (shiftNum == 0) {
            out = str.toCharArray();
        }
        if (shiftNum == 1) {
            out[0] = str.charAt(1); //shifts char at position 0
            out[1] = str.charAt(2); //shifts char at position 1 to pos 2
            out[2] = str.charAt(3); //shifts char at position 2 to pos 3
            out[3] = str.charAt(0); //shifts char at position 3 to pos 1
        }
        if (shiftNum == 2) {
            out[0] = str.charAt(2);
            out[1] = str.charAt(3);
            out[2] = str.charAt(0);
            out[3] = str.charAt(1);
        }
        if (shiftNum == 3) {
            out[0] = str.charAt(3);
            out[1] = str.charAt(0);
            out[2] = str.charAt(1);
            out[3] = str.charAt(2);
        }
        return new String(out);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("SHIFT ROWS: ");
        String[] output = new String[16];
        String random = "AJUYJTXQHUHXICWYYMGHTRKQHQPWKYVGLPYSPWGOINTOFASDF";

        for (int i = 0, n = 0; n < random.length() - 1; i++, n += 4) {
            String substring = random.substring(n, 4 + n);
            if (i == 0) {
                output[0] = substring;
            } else {
                output[i] = shiftRows(substring, i % 4);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            System.out.println(output[i]);
        }
    }
}
```